# How can I change the default picture of the contacts?

Tags: calls, contact-photo

As you can see, when I call someone who doesn't have a unique picture, the default picture of the contacts looks like this:

[image: screenshot]

And I want to see something different or less pixelated for instance.
Is there anyway to change that picture to something else?

***note: I have a rooted phone.**

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to do that. At least not easily as one needs to root and modify and/or replace **phone.apk** and **contacts.apk** with a different resource file with "unknown" icon.

Easier alternatives can be alternative dialers. You can find them in Google Play.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I do have a rooted phone. What should I do next?

Comment: Now this is another question: **"How to modify phone.apk?"** And I have no clue if you are familiar with Android development and reverse engineering tools. Try searching on **XDA forums and simmilar sites** for **phone.apk** and **contacts.apk** mods. You can try some ready-made modifications first. There are also how-to discussions if you wish to create your own mod.

Comment: For example you will need a tool like **android-apktool** to decode resources to and rebuild them after making some modifications. https://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/

Comment: You can also build from source code. And to install your .apk files you will need to get familiar with **adb** (Android Debug Bridge) command line tool. http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html As said in my first answer it is not an easy task :)